USB Python Script Issue Raspberry Pi OS
I'm encountering an issue where I'm trying to trigger a Python script in the background upon
plugging in up to four USB devices, all with the same USB vendor and product IDs.
To accomplish this, I've created a udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/myrule.rules as follows:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1234", ATTR{idProduct}=="5678", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="usb-trigger.service"

1234 and 5689 are just examples.
Additionally, I've set up a systemd service in /etc/systemd/system/usb-trigger.service with the following configuration:
[Unit]
Description=USB Trigger Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/my/python/script/uart.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

However, the script is sometimes executed and sometimes not. Furthermore, if I plug in more than the first device or the second device, the background script fails to start. Occasionally, none of the devices work as expected.
The primary goal of my Python script is to generate a CSV file upon plugging in a USB device, save the data, and close the file when the device is unplugged. I need this script to handle up to four devices.
Here's the Python script I'm using:
python
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import time
import csv
import datetime
import sys

def get_current_time():
    current_time = time.time()
    milliseconds = int((current_time - int(current_time)) * 1000)
    formatted_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(current_time))
    formatted_time += f".{milliseconds:03d}"  # Adding milliseconds
    return formatted_time

def write_to_csv(writer, data):
    try:
        writer.writerow(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error writing to CSV: {e}")

def find_com_port():
    try:
        com_ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        for port in com_ports:
            if port.device.startswith('/dev/ttyUSB') or port.device.startswith('/dev/ttyACM'):
                return port.device
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error finding COM port: {e}")

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            com_port = find_com_port()
            if com_port is not None:
                print(f"COM port found: {com_port}")
                break  # Exit the loop once a COM port is found
            else:
                print("No COM port found. Retrying...")
                time.sleep(1)      

        if com_port is None:
            print("No COM port found.")
            return

        filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + ".csv"
        bottle_id = None
        bottle_id_collected = False  # Flag to track if bottle ID has been collected

        with serial.Serial(port=com_port, baudrate=460800, timeout=2) as ser, open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
            print(f"Connected to {com_port} successfully.")
            writer = csv.writer(file)

            while True:
                received_bytes = ser.readline().decode('ascii', errors='replace').strip()
                if received_bytes:
                    if not bottle_id_collected and 'Bottle ID' in received_bytes:
                        bottle_id = received_bytes.split('Bottle ID')[1].strip()
                        writer.writerow(['Bottle ID', bottle_id])
                        writer.writerow(['Input 1', 'Input 2', 'Input 3', 'time stamp'])
                        bottle_id_collected = True
                    else:
                        parts = received_bytes.split(', ')
                        try:
                            numbers = [float(part) for part in parts]
                            data_row = numbers + [get_current_time()]
                            writer.writerow(data_row)
                            print(f"Writing to CSV: {data_row}") 
                            file.flush()  # Force flushing
                        except ValueError as e:
                            pass
                time.sleep(0.01)

    except serial.SerialException as e:
        print(f"Error opening serial port {com_port}: {e}")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program terminated by user.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    finally:
        try:
            if 'ser' in locals() and ser.is_open:
                ser.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error closing serial port: {e}")

        try:
            if 'file' in locals() and not file.closed:
                file.close()


        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error closing CSV file: {e}")

        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Any insights into why the script behaves inconsistently and how I can ensure it runs reliably upon plugging in multiple USB devices would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I configured a udev rule and systemd service to trigger a Python script upon plugging in multiple USB devices with identical IDs. I expected the script to reliably generate a CSV file for each device, handling up to four devices simultaneously. However, the script sometimes failed to start, especially with multiple devices plugged in, leading to inconsistent behavior.

Instead of having to deal with multitasking and services, I'd suggest just running a single Python script with a loop that checks for new devices every 0.1 s or so and handles them.  I suspect systemd doesn't want to run more than one copy of the service at a time, does that explain all your issues?  You can run journalctl -xu usb-trigger to maybe get more insight into what's going wrong.  Definitely get it working with 1 device first before moving to multiple devices.

HI David, I am already able to run one script per device, but issues arise when I attempt to trigger more than one device simultaneously. Should I write different services for each device I plug in? With just one, I am able to address the problem, although not entirely. If you have any tips or suggestions, please share them with me. Thank you .

PS : i also added this two lines to the scripts, this in the Service script ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/my/python/script/uart.py and this to the top of the Python one #!/usr/bin/env python3 and the problem stil unsolved.

Your script doesn't take any arguments so how does it know which device to connect to when there are multiple ones?

If you want multiple instances, you need to explicitly turn your .service into a multi-instance (templated) unit. Otherwise, if one instance is still running, the second start will do nothing. This applies to all service types – even to Type=oneshot services.

Rename your unit to usb-trigger@.service.
This allows multiple instances of the service, with different values after the @.

Change the udev rule to ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="usb-trigger@%k.service".
Udev will replace %k or $kernel with the "kernel name" such as ttyUSB2. You can look through the udev(7) manual page for other suitable things.
(Since unit instance names are limited in what characters they may use, anything fancier than %k will likely need to be passed through the systemd-escape tool.)

Change your ExecStart to pass %i as an argument to the script.
ExecStart=/path/to/my/python/script/uart.py %i

(If you used systemd-escape in udev, then use %I instead; it will undo the escaping.)

Change your script to read the device name from sys.argv (preferably using argparse).
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("device")
args = parser.parse_args()

print(f"I was called for {device!r}", file=sys.stderr) # ¹


Remove the now-unnecessary "find_com_port()" code from your script.



¹ (On that note, you really should use stderr for error messages. If using stdout, then you should also configure stdout to be line-buffered via sys.stdout.reconfigure(...), as otherwise messages can get buffered and won't show up immediately in the journal.
And you should use syslog instead of all that, e.g. via syslog.syslog() or via the logging module's SysLogHandler, as it forces you to specify the priorities of each message – which makes scrolling through journalctl much more pleasant when important messages are highlighted.)
